# Using a single static IP address as LoadBalancerIP across multiple services with different ports

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to expose a stateful mongo replica set running on my cluster for outside access.

I have three replicas and I have created a `LoadBalancer` service for each replica with the same `LoadBalancerIP` while incrementing the port sequentially from `10255` to `10257`.

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: mongo-service-0
      namespace: datastore
      labels:
        app: mongodb-replicaset
   spec:
      loadBalancerIP: staticip
      type: LoadBalancer
      externalTrafficPolicy: Local
      selector:
        statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: mongo-mongodb-replicaset-0
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 10255
          targetPort: 27017
```

The issue is that only one service `mongo-service-0` is deployed successfully with static IP, the other timeout after a while.

What I am trying to figure out is if I can use a single static IP address as LoadBalancerIP across multiple services with different ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using different ports for each of your Mongo replicas you had to create different Kubernetes [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for each one of the replicas.  You can only tie a Kubernetes service with a single load balancer and each load balancer will have its own unique IP (or IPs) address, so you won't be able to share that IP address across a [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) type of Service.

The workaround is to use a [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) service and basically manage your load balancer independently and point it to the NodePort for each one of your replicas.

Another workaround is to use the same port on your Mongo replicas and use the same Kubernetes LoadBalancer service. Is there any reason why you are not using that?

Comment: I wanted to be able to access each replica individually

Comment: Three load balancers on 3 different node ports

Comment: I'll try that, but that will mean three different LoadBalancer IPs

Comment: No if you use your own load balancer

Comment: If you want independence it will be 3 IPs regardless